# Updating two tables using prepared statements and PDO

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, pdo

Am trying to update data in two tables and according to my codes below, only the first table 'student_information' is getting updated
leaving out the 'training_information' table not updated. The two tables are linked by IndexNo. I need guidance with my code on how I can update both the tables at once using my sample prepared statements.
Please follow also that I try to get the id value using the URL as given. This helps me view and update data about one distinct column with IndexNo in one operation.

```
 URL: http://localhost/sample/updateStudentInfo.php?id=14
```

updateStudentInfo.php code as below

```
            <?php
                // Connect to MySQL database
                    function connect(){
                        try{
                            $dbConn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=hpcz', 'root', 'root');
                            $dbConn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                            return $dbConn;
                        }
                        catch(PDOException $e){
                            echo $e->getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                $dbh = connect();
                //gets the value of the id from the URL     
                $id = htmlspecialchars($_GET["id"]); 

                $sql = "SELECT 
            student_information.IndexNo,
            student_information.SurName,
            student_information.FirstName,
            student_information.MiddleName,
            grade_obtained.Grade,
            secondary_school.SchoolName

                            FROM student_information

                            LEFT JOIN training_information
                            ON student_information.IndexNo = training_information.IndexNo


                            WHERE student_information.IndexNo='$id'";
                            $result = $dbh->prepare($sql);
                            $result->execute();
                            while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                    {

                            //Initializing the id from URL with the IndexNo from the database
                                $id=$row["IndexNo"];

                ?>

            <div><form method="post" >
                <table  width="500" border="1" >
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="4">Update Student Information</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <td colspan="4"><div align="center"><strong>Applicant Information</strong></div></td>
                 </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><div align="right">Sur Name:</div></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" value="<?php echo $row['SurName']; ?>"/></td>
                    <td><div align="right">First Name:</div></td>
                    <td><input type="text"  text-input" name="fname" id="fname" value="<?php echo $row['FirstName']; ?>"/></td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td><div align="right">Middle Name:</div></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="mname" id="mname" value="<?php echo $row['MiddleName']; ?>"/></td>
                    <td><div align="right">NRC/Passport No:</div></td>
                    <td><input type="text"  name="nrc" id="nrc" value="<?php echo $row['NRCPassportNo']; ?>"/></td>
                  </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <td colspan="4"><div align="center"><strong>Training Information</strong></div></td>
                 </tr> 
                 <tr>
                    <td><div align="right">Secondary School Attended:</div></td>
                    <td><select name="secondarysch" id="secondarysch" >
                    <option selected="selected"><?php echo $row['SchoolName']; ?></option>
                        </select></td>
                     <td><div align="right">Grade Obtained:</div></td>
                    <td><select name="grade" id="grade" >
                    <option selected="selected"><?php echo $row['Grade']; ?></option>
                        </select></td>
                  </tr>

                    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $row['IndexNo']; ?>"/>
                <tr>
                   <td colspan="4"><div align="center"><button id="update">Update</div></td>
                  </tr>
                  </table>
            <?php }?>       
            </form>
```

JavaScript code:

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#update").click(function(){
                    /*Applicant Information*/
                    var vid = $("#id").val();
                    var vsurname = $("#surname").val();
                    var vmname = $("#mname").val();
                    var vfname = $("#fname").val();
                    /*Training Information*/
                    var vsecondarysch = $("#secondarysch").val();
                    var vgrade = $("#grade").val();
                    /*Jquery post method */

                    $.post("http://localhost/sample/sendUpdateStudentInfo.php", 
                        {
                            id : vid,
                            surname : vsurname,
                            mname : vmname,
                            fname : vfname,
                            secondarysch :vsecondarysch,
                            grade : vgrade
                        },
                        /*Handles response from server*/
                        function(response){
                            alert(response);
                        });
                    alert("You are here");
                  });
               });
```

sendUpdateStudentInfo.php code:

```
       <?php
        $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];


        function connect(){
            try{
                $dbConn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=hpcz', 'root', 'root');
                $dbConn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                return $dbConn;
            }
            catch(PDOException $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        /*Checks if method is HTTP POST*/
        if(strtolower($method) == 'post'){
            /*Applicant Information*/
            $id = addslashes($_POST['id']);
            $surname = addslashes($_POST['surname']);
            $mname = addslashes($_POST['mname']);
            $fname = addslashes($_POST['fname']);

            /*Training Information*/
            $secondarysch = addslashes($_POST['secondarysch']);
            $grade = addslashes($_POST['grade']);

            try {

                $dbHandler = connect();
                $dbHandler->beginTransaction();

                $setInfo = "UPDATE student_information 
                                        SET
                                   SurName = :vSurname,
                                   MiddleName = :vMName,
                                   FirstName = :vFName
                                        WHERE 
                                   IndexNo = '$id'";

                $stmt = $dbHandler->prepare($setInfo);

                $stmt->bindParam(':vSurname', $surname);
                $stmt->bindParam(':vMName', $mname);
                $stmt->bindParam(':vFName', $fname);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->closeCursor();

                $setTrainingInfo = "UPDATE  training_information 
                                                SET 
                                            SecondarySchoolID = :Secondarysch,
                                            GradeObtainedID = :Grade
                                                WHERE 
                                            IndexNo = '$id'";

                $stmt = $dbHandler->prepare($setTrainingInfo);

                $stmt->bindParam(':Secondarysch', $secondarysch);
                $stmt->bindParam(':Grade', $grade);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->closeCursor();

                $dbHandler->commit();

                echo "The Operation was Successful!!!!!!";

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                $dbHandler->rollback();
                die($e->getMessage());
            }

        }else{
            echo "Oops! Make sure Method is POST";
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Please add this `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);` on top of your code to show if there are any errors.

Comment: @Akram Fares there are no errors, am using firebug. I think the problem is with the second update query on  " IndexNo = '$id' " it is not being recognized. Thanks!